Trying to use a2lix/TranslationFormBundle with #[Gedmo\Translatable]
I’m currently facing an issue with translating certain fields in my form. The error I’m encountering is:
Field 'name' doesn't exist in App\Entity\ModuleTranslation
It appears that the system is expecting a 'name' field in the ModuleTranslation class. However, this field does not exist in our translation entity; we only have a reference to the field in the database.
Could anyone assist me in resolving this issue?
ModuleClass:
#[Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class: ModuleTranslation::class)]
class Module implements Translatable
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'id', type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'name', type: 'string', length: "255")]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    protected $name;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'description', type: 'string', length: "255", nullable:true)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    protected $description;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'active', type: 'boolean')]
    #[Gedmo\Translatable]
    protected $active;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'module_order', type: 'integer')]
    private $order;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'module_type', type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private $type;

ModuleTranslationClass:
class ModuleTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{

    public function __construct($locale, $field, $value)
    {
        $this->setLocale($locale);
        $this->setField($field);
        $this->setContent($value);
    }

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Module::class, inversedBy: 'translations')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'object_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', onDelete: 'CASCADE')]
    protected $object;
}

Form:
class ModuleForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('translations', TranslationsType::class, [
            'fields' => [
                'name' => [
                    'field_type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'name.',
                    'locale_options' => [
                        'en' => ['label' => 'Name'],
                        'pt' => ['label' => 'Nome'],
                    ],
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => '',
                    ]
                ],
                'description' => [
                    'field_type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'description.',
                    'locale_options' => [
                        'en' => ['label' => 'Description'],
                        'pt' => ['label' => 'Descrição'],
                    ],
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'placeholder' => '',
                    ]
                ],
                'active' => [
                    'field_type' => 'choice',
                    'label' => 'name.',
                    'locale_options' => [
                        'en' => ['label' => 'Name'],
                        'pt' => ['label' => 'Nome'],
                    ],
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control kt-radio-inline',
                    ],
                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'choices'  => ModuleType::$activesAvailable,
                    'required' => true
                ],
            ],
            'locale_labels' => [                        
                'pt' => 'Portuguese',
                'en' => 'English',
            ],
        ]);
$builder
            ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'label' => 'Module Type',
                    'id' => 'task-type',
                    'class' => 'kt-radio-inline',
                ],
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'choices' => ModuleType::$typesAvailable,
                'required' => true
            ])
            ->add('quantity', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'label' => 'Quantity Type',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'placeholder' => ''
                ],
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('icon', TextareaType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'rows' => '8',
                    'label' => 'Icon Code',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                ],
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('color', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'label' => 'Color',
                    'class' => 'form-control jscolor',
                    'placeholder' => ''
                ],
                'required' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

